# Merge date from one datetime and time from another datetime

Tags: mysql

I'm maintaining a database where the date and the time of events are seperated, both are saved as datetime though.

So How do I pull the date from the "date" Column, and the time from the "time" column and insert it into the "datetime"-column

Comment: That's a really weird database schema but it sounds like you're not to blame, you just inherited it!

Comment: pr1001: Yep, I have no idea what the previous developer was smoking ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in your selects.

For the date:

```
'%Y-%m-%d'
```

For time:

```
'%H:%i:%s'
```

So something like:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `datetimecol` = CONCAT_WS(' ', DATE_FORMAT(`datecol`, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(`timecol`, '%H:%i:%s'))
```