# Merging two columns of fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge date from one datetime and time from another datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383133/merge-date-from-one-datetime-and-time-from-another-datetime)

How can I physically merge two MySQL column/fields into one column/field without losing any data on it

Specifically I will be combining a DATE and TIME column/field

thanks

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383133/merge-date-from-one-datetime-and-time-from-another-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your timestamp field, initialize it with the [`timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function, and then once you feel safe, drop the old columns. Something like this:

```
alter table your_table add timestamp_column timestamp;
update your_table set timestamp_column = timestamp(date_column, time_column);
-- Pause and make sure everything is okay.
-- Take your time, the database will wait.
alter table your_table drop column date_column;
alter table your_table drop column time_column;
alter table your_table modify timestamp_column timestamp not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

By "merge", do you mean "add"? It sounds like you've got the date and time in separate fields, and so putting them together is the same thing as adding them.

If that's the case, you can use the MySQL's `ADDTIME()` function:

```
mysql> SELECT ADDTIME(aDate, aTime) FROM aTable;
```

If you mean to concatenate them, then MySQL has a CONCAT() function... But it doesn't seem suited for your purpose.

--edited--

If it's another column you're after, it's a two step process:

```
-- Add the column
mysql> ALTER TABLE aTable ADD COLUMN aDateTime DateTime DEFAULT NULL;
-- Insert the data
mysql> UPDATE aTable SET aDateTime = ADDTIME(aDate, aTime);
```

But after this point, you'll have to maintain it in all three columns. That is, `aDateTime` won't automatically update when you add/change `aDate` or `aTime`.

Comment: what I mean is to combine the two columns into one physically, which means there will be a new column that will be created. any solutions that I can make it? thanks

Comment: Ah, got it. Just edited the answer. I don't have a terminal in front of me, so it's completely untested... But it should help you on your way.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked and I learned something from it thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

i dont wanna if you want to create a new field but just in case you wanna do it

```
alter table t add yournewfield datetime not null; 
UPDATE table t  SET younerwfield = addtime(t.date,t.time);
```

Comment: alter table threads add dtposted datetime not null; 
UPDATE table threads  SET dtposted = addtime(threads.dateposted,threads.dateposted);

I did something like that, the column was successfully created but there is an error on the UPDATE statement

Comment: make sure that all the attributes have the right names